# Why rust compiler emits so strange SIMD code?

Tags: assembly, rust, compilation, compiler-optimization, simd

Suppose following code which basically generates monotonically increasing slice of numbers.

```rust
pub struct RangePostingList {
    next: u64,
    end: u64,
}

fn next_batch_scalar(pl: &mut RangePostingList, target: u64, buffer: &mut [u64]) -> usize {
    pl.next = pl.next.max(target);
    if pl.next >= pl.end {
        return 0;
    }
    let range_len = (pl.end - pl.next) as usize;
    let len = range_len.min(buffer.len());

    for i in 0..len {
        buffer[i] = pl.next;
        pl.next += 1;
    }

    len
}
```

When compiling this code with `-C opt-level=3 -Ctarget-cpu=native` rustc is producing 2 versions of a loop: SIMD and scalar ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5YM1a9sWv)). Those loops are selected in runtime based on a threshold of 17 elements. If there are at least 17 elements to process, SIMD implementation is used, otherwise we fallback to scalar implementation (`cmp r8, 17` in assembly). In benchmark I can confirm that if code is called with a slice of 17 elements throughput of a function raise drastically.

So the questions are:

1. why threshold is so strange? I though threshold always should be multiple of lane count for used SIMD register. So in my case it should be multiple of 4, I guess.
2. if the most frequent case is a function called with a buffer of length 16, how to tell a compiler to generate SIMD implementation for this case?

Comment: Exactly, still I don't understand why it's 17? It should be 16 or some other multiple of 4.

Comment: but before `inc r8` there is `lea r8, [rax - 1]` which cancels `inc` :)

Comment: The vectorized loop looks like it should work for sizes of 16 or higher (the cleanup can handle 0 or more elements), so it's a missed optimization or off-by-one in the vectorizer that the loop prologue chooses to jump to the scalar cleanup for size 16.  Unless I'm missing something.  You could try hand-modifying the asm and checking if it still passes a test suite.  (Make the function noinline to make sure each test actually calls into the one version you modify.)